# Qt performance when running executable outside of Qt Creator is awful!

Tags: qt, dll, performance

I just tried running a program that I've been developing with Qt outside of Qt.  I double clicked on the program in /release, resolve all the missing DLLs, and find that my app has awful slow performance compared to when it is launched from within Qt Creator.  What might be the reason for this?!

Comment: What means *I've been developing with Qt outside of Qt*?

Comment: @mosg: "outside of Qt" should have read "not from within the QtCreator IDE".

Comment: I thing, that there is no differents between QtCreator build and console QMake/mingw, because both this build used one compiler/linker. Did you try to build you code with Qt+MSVC?

Comment: What is slow, startup and/or execution?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have never encountered this. Is there any files you are loading in your application which is big enough to make the application load slow? Like reading a big flat file and get the contents out of it. If so, just make sure that the file's contents hasn't changed while you were running through Qt Creator and when you run it outside. It's my guess though. For me, the performances doesn't have much differences in either cases.